# how to edit recipients,tabs without docusign account

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use DocuSign in my app, it’s really an excellent tool, however, I've met some problems and hope you could help me with
it, thanks.

First of all, let me explain my scenario, let’s say Annie who are using my app, Annie opens a document in the app, she generate a digital
signature of her own on the document, then she shares the document to Tom and invite Tom to sign his name on the document.

I leveraged DocuSign Api with the following step to complete the above scenario:

1. For each document user opened, create an envelope
2. Open console/sender view in embedded h5 view
3. User will sign his/her name and edit it in embedded view

My questions are:

·User needs to have a DocuSign account to use console/sender view, but Annie or Tom don’t have an account and may not would like to register a DocuSign account in the app.

Is it possible for me to create an account for Annie through some kind of Api?

·         Even if they already have valid accounts, Annie signs her name on the document, when she wants to invite Tom to sign on the document on a certain place, she have no way to find Tom on the page she edited as DocuSign do not know Tom and I could not add Tom’s information on the page.

Is there any kind of method that I can show Annie’s contacts on the page and let Annie to select any contact on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My questions are:

> User needs to have a DocuSign account to use console/sender view, but Annie or Tom don’t have an account and may not would like to register a DocuSign account in the app.

The ***sender*** of the signing request needs an account. The sender can be either a "system" account (your application) or a human. Often a human's account is used, that way he or she will receive back information about the signing progress, will see the signed document stored in DocuSign, etc.

> Is it possible for me to create an account for Annie through some kind of Api?

Yes, your app (and your account) can be enabled to use the API to provision new sender accounts. These accounts cost money, so in this case, your company is reselling DocuSign services to your end customers. DocuSign is happy to work with you to enable this.

> Even if they already have valid accounts, Annie signs her name on the document, when she wants to invite Tom to sign on the document on a certain place, she have no way to find Tom on the page she edited as DocuSign do not know Tom and I could not add Tom’s information on the page.
>
> Is there any kind of method that I can show Annie’s contacts on the page and let Annie to select any contact on it?

If your app is creating the envelope via the API, then your app can show Annie a list of recipients and let Annie pick Tom via *your app*. Then your app creates the envelope/transaction/signing request in DocuSign, including Annie and Tom as signers.

Then, via the Sender View, Annie can see the document before it is sent. Your app can do more than just add Tom as a signer: your app can add the "tabs" that control where Tom will sign, initial, and make other updates to the signed doc.

DocuSign DTM is a large system, so there is often "more than one way to do it." Please ask additional questions by opening new questions on Stack Overflow.